# Disable constructor for non-const instances

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a simple class and I'm hoping to keep it simple. The only wrinkle is that I want to conditionally disable a constructor for non-const instances.

I'd like to do something like:

```
struct X {
    template<typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<this>::value>>
    X(...) {
        ....
    }
};
```

However, that doesn't work for several reasons. Is there a way to do something along those lines?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Objects are never `const` in their constructor and destructor, so you can't know from within that you're initializing an ultimately `const` object.